# i need to do is generate back the json object to string array using android and have to create the data and check boxes dynamically on the screen

Tags: android

```
  //this is my android code MainActivity   
  package com.example.desktop4.jsonandroid;

  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.content.Intent;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.widget.Button;
  import android.widget.EditText;
  import android.widget.TextView;

  import com.example.sairamkrishna.myapplication.R;
  import com.google.gson.Gson;

  public class MainActivity extends Activity {
      Gson gson = new Gson();
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

          final TextView op1 = (TextView)      findViewById(R.id.textView3);
          final TextView op2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
          final TextView op3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
          final TextView op4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);
          final Button b=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
          final EditText t=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
          final Button b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

          String strJson = "{\"questions\":
[{\"id\":1,\"type\":\"RadioButton\",\"qstring\":<br/>
\"wt is the     color\",\"option\":[\"pink\"]},{\"id\":2,\"type\":\"edttxt\",\"qstring\":<br/>
\"wt is the size\",\"option\":[\"size is 4 \"]},{\"id\":3,\"type\":\"chkbox\",\"qstring\":<br/>
\"this is text box\",\"option\":[\"Test5\"]}]}"; //string to obj converted


           //the generated gson is in object form and pasted in the <br/>    android code// 
          //now i want to convert data dynamically and able to generate <br/>checkboxes to this data//

          final QuestionSet qs = gson.fromJson(strJson,QuestionSet.class);
             b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                  @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                     String s=t.getText().toString();
                                op1.setText(String.valueOf(qs.getQuestions().get(Integer.parseInt(s)).getId()));

                                op2.setText(qs.getQuestions().get(Integer.parseInt(s)).getType().toString());

                                op3.setText(qs.getQuestions().get(Integer.parseInt(s)).getQstring().toString());

                             op4.setText(qs.getQuestions().get(Integer.parseInt(s)).getOption().toString());
                            }
                        });

                    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
         Intent j=new Intent(MainActivity.this ,MainActivity1.class);
                            startActivity(j);

                        }
                    });
                }

            }
```

need to do is generate back the json object to string array using android and  have to create the data and check boxes dynamically on the screen

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically create objects and add it to layout.
 
eg: create a view by
`CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(this);`


add it to layout
`layout.addView(cb);`